# Add New Disks Using LVM to an Existing Linux System

Tags: rhel, filesystems, lvm, disk, fdisk

We want to Add New Disk Using LVM to an Existing Linux System ( according to - [How to Add New Disks Using LVM to an Existing Linux System](https://www.tecmint.com/add-new-disks-using-lvm-to-linux/) )

We have the following rhel 7.2 server details

```
 pvs
  PV         VG      Fmt  Attr PSize             PFree
  /dev/sda2  VOL_GROUP-lv    lvm2 a--  <179.00g <25.09g
  /dev/sdb1  data_vol_g     lvm2 a--  <100.00g      0

NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0  180G  0 disk
├─sda1                8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2                8:2    0  179G  0 part
  ├─VOL_GROUP-lv_root    253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VOL_GROUP-lv_swap    253:1    0  3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─VOL_GROUP-lv_var     253:2    0  100G  0 lvm  /var
sdb                   8:16   0  100G  0 disk
└─sdb1                8:17   0  100G  0 part
  └─data_vol_g-data_lv 253:3    0  100G  0 lvm  /DB


  #  fdisk -l | grep sda
Disk /dev/sda: 193.3 GB, 193273528320 bytes, 377487360 sectors
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   377487359   187694080   8e  Linux LVM
```

Since we have on `Pfree=25 G` , then we want to add a new disk or partition, `sda3`, and the final goal is create an XFS file system on it with `ftype=1`, since the current OS has an XFS file system with `ftype=0`, and we can't install Docker which needs `ftype=1`.

So we start with the `fdisk` , but we get that:

```
 fdisk /dev/sda
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (2 primary, 0 extended, 2 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (3,4, default 3):
No free sectors available

Command (m for help):
```

Why we get "`No free sectors available:`" , while we have `PFree=25G`   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fdisk` says you have no free sectors available because all the disk space is allocated to partitions (`sda1` and `sda2`). Thus from `fdisk`’s perspective, there’s no free disk space, and no room to create a new partition. This can also be seen in `lsblk`’s output:

```
sda                   8:0    0  180G  0 disk
├─sda1                8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2                8:2    0  179G  0 part
```

`sda` is 180G in size, and contains `sda1` which is 1G in size and `sda2` which is 179G in size, so there’s no unused space.

`sda2` is used as a physical volume in your `VOL_GROUP` volume group, and has 25GiB’s worth of available physical extents. This free disk space can be used for logical volumes (LVs), either by adding a new LV, or by resizing an existing LV. The VG with free space is `VOL_GROUP`, so

```
lvcreate VOL_GROUP ...
```

will allow you to create an LV there.